# Can singleton be implemented in OSGi environment

Tags: java, osgi

As far as I understand every bundle in osgi has its own classloader. Let's suppose we have three bundles:1,2,3. There is singleton class in bundle 1. Bundle 2 loads singleton and makes some changes in it. And as far as I understand, if bundle 3 loads singleton too its version of singleton is different. So Singleton in bundle 2 != singleton in bundle 3.

Are my statements right? If they are right, so it is not singleton, is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is true that each bundle has its own classloader, but the classloaders are "shared", depending on the Manifest `import-package` declaration. Each bundle classloader maintain a private mapping table that tells it which classloader is responsible for providing classes from a particular package.
In your case, when bundle 2 loads the singleton, it does not load the Singleton by itself, it asks the bundle 1 classloader for the class.

Comment: The singleton should work in the case of the example above. The disadvantage is that it creates a tight coupling between the bundles. So the OSGi way would be to publish an OSGi service in bundle1 and use it in the other bundles. This will also work like a singleton but still allows each bundle to be updated.

Comment: It's also still possible to have multiple bundles exporting the same package; so you can have multiple instances of the "singleton".