# Netflix Hystrix metrics not visible on /hystrix.stream

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix, hystrix

I'm evaluating [Netflix Hystrix](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix) as improvement for the project I'm currently working on, which is a Java OSGi based one (I'm using Apache felix as OSGi runtime). 
As for now I was able to:

- Inject hystrix core in one existing bundle which act as connector towards an external system and wrap one of its service with an HystrixCommand . Everything is working as expected, I can see hystrix logic working. Also with the help of DEBUG logs I checked that all is registered properly (com.netflix.hystrix=DEBUG).
- Create a new bundle which is responsible of registering the hystrix.stream servlet. Basically I retrieved the HttpService (org.osgi.service.http.HttpService) coming from the OSGi runtime, and registered the servlet on it. All seems fine, servlet is registered properly and visible at ${myEndpoint}/hystrix.stream.  This way:

  httpService.registerServlet("/hystrix.stream/*", new HystrixMetricsStreamServlet(), null, myHttpCtx);

Problem is that I cannot see **data** objects pushed in the stream. Only **ping** updates are visible, even if at the same time i'm stressing HistryxCommand warpped service with a Jmeter/Postman test.
Given that I'm not noticing errors, I'm thinking of different streams getting used by the publisher and the reader logic. Can someone help me in understanding a bit more of the internals of Hystrix and troubleshoot my scenario ? I tried looking at the Hystrix sources but to be honest this did not help for the time being.

Below dependencies i'm using

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.netflix.hystrix</groupId>
            <artifactId>hystrix-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.netflix.hystrix</groupId>
            <artifactId>hystrix-metrics-event-stream</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.12</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I observed that instantiating both **HystrixCommand** classes and **HystrixMetricsStreamServlet** from the **same** OSGi bundle solved my issues.

So I guess the issue was caused by:

- usage of singletons in Hystrix internal classes;
- the fact that in OSGi each bundle has its own classloader, [with its pro and cons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37321168/can-singleton-be-implemented-in-osgi-environment).

Looking at Hystrix source code this is my understanding of the internal process:

HystrixCommandMetrics singleton is used by AsbtractCommand classes to push events metrics. 
HystrixCommandMetrics singleton is also referenced by HystrixMetricsStreamServlet (through HystrixDashboardStream class) to read the same events metrics. 
So if HystrixMetricsStreamServlet and AbstractCommand(s) don't share the same classloaders they're reading and pushing from/on different objects.

Since I plan to use Hystrix to wrap different systems, hence in different OSGi bundles, a clean solution I found as of now is to pack all required Hystrix libraries in a single com.mycompany.osgi.hystrix and make it available on the OSGi runtime as standalone plugin.